hyphen between pages in references are missing
I'm new to Overleaf and facing a problem I don't understand.
Problem:
I'm currently designing my Referencing style (CTR Harvard 12th edition). Somehow Zotero exports the hyphens as double (like in the picture). The compiled version of this reference doesn't show the hyphen between the pages at all. I don't understand this problem because the hyphens in the ISSN field are working as they should.


I know it is not the minimal example but maybe something in my settings is causing this issue:
% Layout
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=35mm,right=25mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,paper=a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[english, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}% Recommended
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[skip=1pt]{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{myformat}{\fontsize{5}{6}\selectfont#1#2#3}
\captionsetup{format=myformat}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\newcommand\tab[1][1cm]{\hspace*{#1}}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18, width=8cm}


\newenvironment{Figure}
  {\par\medskip\noindent\minipage{\linewidth}}
  {\endminipage\par\medskip}

  \hypersetup{
    colorlinks=false,
    pdfborder={0 0 0},
}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.5mm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{18pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

%References Harvard 
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear, giveninits, uniquename=init, maxcitenames=3, maxbibnames=3,
  urldate=long,innamebeforetitle, articlein=false]{biblatex}

\DeclareDelimFormat*{nameyeardelim}{\addspace}
\DeclareDelimFormat[textcite]{nameyeardelim} {\addspace}
\DeclareDelimFormat[parencite]{nameyeardelim} {\addcomma\addspace}
\DeclareDelimFormat{andothersdelim}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand*{\compcitedelim}{\multicitedelim}
\renewcommand*{\nonameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}

%Citation Harvard
\makeatletter
\AtEveryCitekey{\global\undef\cbx@lastyear}
\makeatother
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareFieldFormat{biblabeldate}{#1}
\DeclareFieldAlias{biblistlabeldate}{biblabeldate}
\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace}
\DeclareDelimFormat{translatortypedelim}{\addspace}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]{title}{#1\isdot}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
  urlfrom   = {available at},
  urlseen   = {accessed},
  bathesis  = {BA},
  mathesis  = {MA},
  phdthesis = {PhD},
}

\newcommand*{\mkbiburlangle}[1]{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\bibstring{urlfrom}\addcolon\space \mkbiburlangle{\url{#1}}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\mkbibparens{\bibcpstring{urlseen}\space#1}}
%\renewcommand*{\jourvoldelim}{\addcomma\space}
%\renewcommand*{\volnumdelim}{}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
%\renewcommand*{\volnumdatedelim}{\addcomma\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat{issuedate}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{doi}{Abger. unter: \url{https://doi.org/#1}}
\addbibresource{zoteroBib.bib}



Looks a bitas if it is there. Do you see it if you zoom in?

what happens if you simply type 2269--2279 somewhere in your document. Does that looks ok?

@mickep thanks for the hint. I can't believe this cost this much time :)

Let me make a guess: you're using MiKTeX.

For anyone facing the same problem, it's just a scope issue, the final document will show the hyphen. Just zoom in and you can see the hyphens on Overleaf as well, as @mickep mentioned it.
